# How to give a class for all descendants of a tree node

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom

Using d3js, in my tree layout, I need to change some properties of a selected node (choix1) and also all its descendants, so I would like to give for all descendants a class (choix2)

```
  .on("click", function() {
    d3.select(this).classed("choix1", true); // selecting a node
    d3.select(".choix1").children.classed("choix2", true); // giving a class (choix2) for all descendants
  })
```

It's ok for the selected node,
I expect a modification in the descendants properties, but the actual properties are the old ones (there is no modifocations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing D3 API with DOM API methods which, obviously, will not work. Trying to access the [`.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) property on the D3 selection returned by `d3.select(".choix1")` breaks because that property is part of the interface [`ParentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode) which is implemented by the DOM's [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) interface being a parent interface of your actual elements.

If you want to use the [`.classed()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_classed) method to set the class on the child elements you have to wrap them into a D3 selection by first calling `.selectAll(this.children)`. Your code thus becomes:

```
.on("click", function() {
  d3.select(this).classed("choix1", true); 
  d3.selectAll(this.children)   // wrap the children in a D3 selection first...
    .classed("choix2", true);   // then call methods on that selection.
})
```

Comment: It still not working !!! note that I'm cibling children and grandchildren and all their descendants,

Comment: @Zied Maybe you should set up an [mcve] demonstrating the issue. It would be much easier to help you out once we can look at what you've actually got.

Comment: For example, using the following code, only the clicked node becomes green !!!

      .on("click", function() {
        d3.select(this).classed("choix1", true); 
        d3.selectAll(this.children)   
          .style("fill","green")
      });